# Elasticsearch two multi_match queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I have three fields `name`, `name.ngram` and `model_number` that I am trying to search. I have boosted `name` so any match on `name` ranks higher than `name.ngram`. However, I still have some cases where the `name.ngram` doesn't match with terms that contain weird punctuation so I want to complete my query with a fuzzy search on the `name` and `model_number` fields field.

Here is the query I ultimately want. If I remove the second multi_match, the query works but does not include the fuzzy search.

```
{
         explain: true,
         query:{
           function_score: { 
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": 
                    {
                      multi_match:{
                         fields: ["name^10", "name.ngram", "model_number"],
                         type: "most_fields",
                         query: "#{query}"
                       },
                       multi_match:{
                           fields: ["name", "model_number"],
                           type: "most_fields",
                           query: "#{query}",
                           fuzziness: "2"
                        }
                    },
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": { 
                      "must": filters
                    }
                  }
               }
             },field_value_factor:{
                    field: "popularity",
                    modifier: "log1p",
                    factor: 5

                 },
                 boost_mode: "sum"
             }
       },highlight: {
            fields: {
              :"*" => {}
            }
          },
        aggs: {categories: { terms: { field: "category.raw"} }} 

      }
```

I want to ultimately treat the fuzzy search like I do the ngram so that non fuzzy matches rank first and fuzzy matches rank second. How do I add a second multi_match query that would allow for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `bool/should` clause is not properly formed, it should be an array with two elements, one for each `multi_match` constraint, like this:

```
  ...
  "should": [
    {
      "multi_match": {
        "fields": [
          "name^10",
          "name.ngram",
          "model_number"
        ],
        "type": "most_fields",
        "query": "#{query}"
      }
    },
    {
      "multi_match": {
        "fields": [
          "name",
          "model_number"
        ],
        "type": "most_fields",
        "query": "#{query}",
        "fuzziness": "2"
      }
    }
  ]
  ...
```